# Does Google App Engine Server block urlfetch on "reddit.com"?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to url fetch "http://www.reddit.com/r/WTF/comments/mv3mw/bad_time_for_smartassery_siri/.json" using httpURLConnection.

When I try with different urls, it just works fine.

when I try running it locally, it also works fine.

It gives me 503, when I deploy it and access it there.

Does anybody know?

Comment: Oh get over yourselves re: all the close votes.

Comment: What gives you a 503? The response from the URLFetch to reddit, or your App Engine app page? Trying this from shell.appspot.com works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going over the deadline.

From the [documentation of fetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html):

> The deadline can be up to a maximum of 60 seconds for request handlers and 10 minutes for tasks queue and cron job handlers. If deadline is None, the deadline is set to 5 seconds.

It defiantly took me longer than 5 seconds to load the page for the first time. I would try setting your fetch to have a longer time-out and see how you go then.

Comment: That wouldn't result in a 503.

Answer (score 0):

No, Google does not block urlfetch requests to Reddit. Reddit, however, may rate limit API requests by source, or their API may simply be slow or unreliable. In my test, requests to Reddit failed often but usually succeeded after a few retries. Similar issues occur with Twitter and other popular, public APIs.

My advice would be to increase your request deadline, and offload HTTP requests to Reddit into tasks. If a request inside a task fails, the task will back off and retry until it succeeds.